# Center vertically a modal div which is not always the same height?

Tags: html, css

So i've got a modal div (set with z-index) that I'm trying to center vertically. The thing is I use it for not only one content but several ones, so the height is not fix. And while having a general "fix" (I'll explain in just after) of -150px in the margin-top generally works for short content, when having a lot of content, the div will start at mid-page and finish at the end (which is not what I want at all). Here is my code :

```
.modal
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -40%;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

So here you can see the "fix". It works kind of well when the content is short :

[image: Short content]

It's pretty ugly when the content is big :

[image: Large content]

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this. Top 50% position the div on the 50% of the container y translate -50% is referred to his height and no the container:

```
.modal {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40%;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/do238Lj1/)

Comment: `top:50%` for what? where is `position`?

Comment: did you try it yourself? Remember OP want to center the modal window..'

Comment: Better use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to make horizontally and vertically center.

Comment: @fcastillo. Wow!! that is genius!! i didnt know you could do it that way. Thanks man.

Comment: @ShahiM thats is not new technique . If you want to read in details how its works check the link .. [verically center in just 3 lines](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Comment: Well it works but... not totally. It centered the whole thing, but now my problem is that I have an animation, and that the thing is translated after the animation. You can see it here (it's very quick after the opening animation, and it happens again if you close and reopen) : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjovM

Comment: Well you could do that without keyframes animation: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPwEb](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPwEb)

Comment: Actually it's not what it does (try again here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjovM the animation is... not the same)

Comment: Check that now! [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPwEb](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPwEb)

Comment: Hi again... Your code works great but for my closing box, I can't get to adapt it. As you can see in my codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXwVYy) which I tried to adapt for the closing (just reverted the things more or less), it doesn't work and does a weird to-the-right animation on the text... Any idea of how to fix that ?

Comment: Yes, you only need to don't remove class BoxIn when you want to hide your box [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbXoOV](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbXoOV)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `css` to center the div. note that this only works on `position:absolute` elements.

```
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
```

So your css will become:

```
.modal
{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: -40%;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that this forces a 80% height, which I don't want (see there : http://i.imgur.com/kPvqZJ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 80%;       
    background: white;        
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as the one just above you, forces a 80% height.